# Retaining Data Across Multiple Activities and Lifecycles

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, persistence

I have a question regarding an Android app I'm developing.  The app is a compilation of multiple different games, and a launcher for those games (basically a screen with a list of the games it can launch).  The way I've structured it, each game, as well as the launcher, is its own Activity.  Then, when the launcher launches a game, it starts the game using an Intent and then closes itself.  The games each have the ability to go back to the Launcher in the same fashion.

The issue is that if the game is ever closed for any reason, even going to another app and then coming back, the game data is deleted completely and the user has to start a new game.  This is, for obvious reasons, undesired.  What I would like to do is, when the game closes, store the current game state in persistent storage and then reload it on app start.  The problem with that being that the launcher and the game activity can't (as far as I'm aware) talk to each other across lifecycle changes.  What is a good way to do the kind of storage I want to do?  Specifically, what I would like to do is, any time the game would need to close and erase its data, to save a) the game being played and b) the state of that game, both to persistent storage.

Also, if I've completely FUBAR'd any hope at doing this due to my app design, let me know that too.  I've structured it this way (with multiple Activities) because it seemed like the easiest thing to do at the time, but if I've messed something up by trying this, I'm open to fixing that too.

Thanks!

Comment: If an activity is getting destroyed by the OS then onSavedInstance will be called in this bundle you can save the game state and when the activity is recreated you can get this content back means, OnCreate method will be called along with the saved bundle. Now if the user click back button from the current game save the game state either to the shared preference or database according to the values you are going to save and once user comes back to the same game again fetch the saved game details from the saved space and recreate the user state. This is a basic outline.

Comment: Shared preferences is a good place to store information. It is also really easy to erase if need be.

Comment: The problem with that is that each game is its own Activity. Therefore I can't pass data across them, even through SavedPreferences.

Comment: (because I can't add a newline in my comment apparently) Also I tried a system where I store the game state in SavedPreferences and then delete it after reading it back after game load, and it didn't erase properly so it caused the game to lock in a particular state.  I tried both SavedPreferences.editor.clear and SavedPreferences.editor.erase, and yes I did call commit().